# I am getting 404 Resource not found error while executing Servlet Can any one rectify it?

Tags: java, servlets

Below is my Servlet code:

```
import javax.servlet.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class HelloWorldServlet extends GenericServlet
    {
       public void service(ServletRequest request,ServletResponse response)throws ServletException,IOException
       {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("<HTML>");
            out.println("<BODY BGCOLOR = yellow>");
            out.println("<H1>Hello Web World!</H1>");
            out.println("<BODY>");
            out.println("</HTML>");
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

Below is web.xml:

```
<web-app>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I placed the web.xml in WEB-INF folder.But even though it is showing resource not found error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will hit proper url,you will be good.
In my case `http://localhost:8080/MyWebapp/hello` worked.

`Note`- If your servlet is in a package,then specify classname with package like this in your `web.xml`.

```
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>your.package.HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
```

Comment: Yes you are correct @Prince Mani Gupta after I had given the url "http://localhost:8080/MyWebapp/hello".It successfully executed.Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

"I placed the web.xml in WEB-INF folder.But even though it is showing resource not found error."

web.xml file must be inside WEB-INF folder.

`<servlet-class> HelloWorldServlet </servlet-class>`

Inside  tag you must specify the **fully qualified class path** (including package name).

As a convention we do not use same name for `<servlet-name>` and `<servlet-class>`. The whole purpose of using mappings will be worthless. We use a different name for *servlet-name* becuase that will be visible in the client's browser.

Comment: Thank you @Jude Niroshan for your answer